# How should I draw and move my Java Pacman

Tags: java, graphics, drawing, pacman

I need some help with a Java assignment I have, I'm required to build a clone of Pac-Man.

The problem is, I don't know how to draw the movements of the Pac-Man or the Ghosts. I'm thinking I should only draw the walls once, and continiously redraw the characters, but I don't know how I should do it or what methods of drawing I should use.

Comment: Hello there! Please read [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example as to what you have already tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, it is no good idea not to redraw the complete GUI of any game you write several times each second (the quotient of complete redraws over a second is referred to as the 'frame-rate' of a game). If you do not do this, you might observe weird effects like: The contents look strange if you resize or move the window in case its not displayed in full-screen, there might by weird graphical effects, and, most important, the images of your game-characters won't disappear at their previous positions, if you do not draw the background over them again.

Common approach is to set up a Thread that is not doing anything else but invoking some redraw methods about 60 times each second (60 fps (frames per second) appear fluent to the human eye as our temporal resolution lies in that scale) and to use another Thread that updates the position data of the characters and passes it to the draw-Thread together with the static wall-position-data.

Comment: any ideas on what library I could use for the drawing part?

Comment: @Oreborous See [**LWJGL**](https://www.lwjgl.org/), [**JOGL**](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/), [**Java3D**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-jsp-138252.html).

Comment: That is if you are interested in using an intense Graphical Library. The most simple, and absolutely terrible (yet I still do it) is to use `java.awt.image.BufferedImage`'s and move them around the screen. No libraries required.

Comment: I already programmed some easy games, too, and most of the time I did not even use BufferedImages but simply painted everything with methods of the Graphics class.